# how to fill empty array with objects updated in directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-directive

I started my adventure with Angular directives.
Somewhere in my app I have to choose number of passengers. Then I have to assign "First Name" and "Last Name" for each of them. 
[image]
So I created simple directive for creating html template for that and used it in ng-repeat:

```
app.directive('ngDoubleInputBox', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      'heading': '@?',
      'leftInputHeading': '@?',
      'rightInputHeading': '@?',
      'headingNumber': '@?',
      'passenger' : '='
    },
    templateUrl: '/src/html/doubleInput.html'
  }
});
```

and doubleInput.html :

```
<div class="inputContainer">
  <div class="containerTitle">{{headingNumber}}{{heading}}</div>
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group leftInputContainer">
      <label for="left-input">{{leftInputHeading}}</label>
      <div>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="left-input" ng-model="passenger.firstName">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group rightInputContainer">
      <label for="right-input">{{rightInputHeading}}</label>
      <div>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="right-input" ng-model="passenger.lastName">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Usage:

```
<div class="flightPassengersContent" ng-repeat="passenger in getPassengers() track by $index">
  <ng-double-input-box
  heading-number="{{$index + 1}}" heading=". Passenger"
  left-input-heading="First name" right-input-heading="Last name"
  model={{passenger}}>
  </ng-double-input-box>
</div>
```

I do only have amount of passengers and empty array.

```
  $scope.getPassengers = function() {
    return new Array($scope.passengersAmmount);
  };
```

So my question is: 
How to create an array of data that I could use here? Is it a good approach for passing array elements into directive and change them? If so, how to prepare such array? I tried to create some default passenger objects with null values and get rid of **track by $index"** statement but it didnt work.

Any ideas?

Regards,
Michal

Comment: What creates `$scope.passengersAmmount`? The empty list of passengers should be created when that value is created or modified.

Answer (score 0):

I had to fix my directive and its usage(replaced **passenger** property into **model** property):

directive:

```
app.directive('ngDoubleInputBox', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    scope: {
      'heading': '@?',
      'leftInputHeading': '@?',
      'rightInputHeading': '@?',
      'headingNumber': '@?',
      'model':'='
    },
    templateUrl: '/src/html/doubleInput.html'
  }
});
```

usage :

```
<ng-double-input-box
heading-number="{{$index + 1}}" heading=". Passenger"
left-input-heading="First name" right-input-heading="Last name"
model=passenger>
</ng-double-input-box>
```

template :

```
<div>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="model.firstName">
</div>
```

@georgeawg I was able to remove **track by $index** and avoid error:

*Error: ngRepeat:dupes Duplicate Key in Repeater*

after replacing:

```
$scope.getPassengers = function() {
    return new Array($scope.passengersAmmount);
};
```

with

```
  (function initializeEmptyPassengers() {
    $scope.passengers = [];
    for(i=0; i< $scope.passengersAmmount; i++) {
      $scope.passengers.push(
        {}
      );
    };
  })();

  $scope.getPassengers = function() {
    return $scope.passengers;
  };
```

So now I am working on array with empty objects and pass this objects into directive, but this is not very clean solution for me. Does anyone know if its possible to work with
 **ng-repeat track by $index** with same results but without previous array initialization?